# Can't create spanner instance emulator in minikube

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, minikube, google-cloud-spanner, google-cloud-spanner-emulator

On local environment, use [spanner](https://cloud.google.com/spanner)'s docker emulator to create development tools.

If use minikube, run its docker in kubernetes environment, can start its container

```
minikube start
eval $(minikube docker-env)
docker run -p 9010:9010 -p 9020:9020 gcr.io/cloud-spanner-emulator/emulator
```

But can't create an instance via `gcloud` command

```
gcloud spanner instances create test-env --config=emulator-config --description="Local dev instance" --nodes=1
```

It became pending.

When use an environment without minikube, I can start docker and create an instance

```
docker run -p 9010:9010 -p 9020:9020 gcr.io/cloud-spanner-emulator/emulator
gcloud spanner instances create test-env --config=emulator-config --description="Local dev instance" --nodes=1
gcloud spanner instances list
```

It seems can't run `gcloud spanner` command under minikube's docker-env. Why?

Comment: Are you getting an error or any descritption message about the issue?

Comment: @llompalles No, just pending.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce your issue but I couldn't since I am not sure about your parameters in the `emulator-config`. I think it would be more appropriate to open this issue under the [Spanner emulator Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-spanner-emulator/issues) with a full reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing `eval $(minikube docker-env)` configures environment to use minikube’s Docker daemon (https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/docker-env/).

Thus, emulator is running "inside" the docker domain that is running "inside" the minikube cluster.

You can verify the same by sshing into the minikube cluster using `ssh minikube` to see the list of running processes. You can then do a curl on `http://localhost:9020/v1/projects/test-project/instances`, which should return a result immediately.

Answer (score 0):

This seems likely due to the port not being exposed.

By default, minikube only exposes ports 30000-32767. You can change that with the following:

```
minikube start --extra-config=apiserver.service-node-port-range=1-65535
```

https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#increasing-the-nodeport-range